# Pass Value between two class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, class, dart

How can pass two String between two class? I have a Signin Class where i have two TextField for email and password. Then I have a Button class but I don't know how get email and password String.
I would not create a single class to keep tidy my code.

This is my code:

SigninClass

```
import 'package:cleverpot/Activity/home.dart';
import 'package:cleverpot/Helper/authelper.dart';
import 'package:cleverpot/signin/signout/Header.dart';
import 'package:cleverpot/signin/signout/InputField.dart';
import 'package:cleverpot/signin/signout/InputWrapper.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Signup extends StatefulWidget {
  Signup({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _nameState createState() => _nameState();
}

class _nameState extends State<Signup> {
  String email = "";
  String password = "";
  authHelper _helper = authHelper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                colors: [Colors.green, Colors.greenAccent])),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 80,
            ),
            Header(),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green[300],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(60))),
              child: InputWrapper(),
            ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

InputWrapper Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'Button.dart';
import 'InputField.dart';

class InputWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  InputWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InputWrapperState createState() => _InputWrapperState();
}

class _InputWrapperState extends State<InputWrapper> {
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: InputField(),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: "Password dimenticata?",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      print("Cliccato");
                    })),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Button(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green[500],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
            child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                    text: "Non sei registrato? Clicca qua",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                      ..onTap = () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
                            opaque: false,
                            pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
                              return Registration();
                            }));
                        print("Cliccato");
                      })),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

InputField Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InputField extends StatefulWidget {
  InputField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InputFieldState createState() => _InputFieldState();
}

class _InputFieldState extends State<InputField> {
  String password = '';
  String email = '';

  String getil() {
    return password;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Color(4294638330)))),
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter your email",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                border: InputBorder.none),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Color(4294638330)))),
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                password = value;
                print(password);
              });
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter your password",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                border: InputBorder.none),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

And Button Class:

```
import 'package:cleverpot/Helper/authelper.dart';
import 'package:cleverpot/signin/signout/InputField.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  authHelper _helper = authHelper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.cyan[500],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print(fieldState.getil());
          },
          child: Text(
            "Accedi",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have to get Email and Password from InputField in InputWrapper and put inside Button Class in InputWrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *Lift your state up*. This is a general advice in flutter, the state variables should be contained in a stateful widget which is common to every widget you want to share the variables to.

In your case something like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Signup extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter, colors: [Colors.green, Colors.greenAccent])),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 80,
            ),
            Header(),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green[300],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(60), topRight: Radius.circular(60))),
                child: InputWrapper(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InputWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  InputWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InputWrapperState createState() => _InputWrapperState();
}

class _InputWrapperState extends State<InputWrapper> {
  String email = '';
  String password = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: InputField(
              email: email,
              password: password,
              onEmailChanged: (value) => setState(() => email = value),
              onPasswordChanged: (value) => setState(() => password = value),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: "Password dimenticata?",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      print("Cliccato");
                    })),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Button(password: password),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green[500], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: "Non sei registrato? Clicca qua",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onTap = () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      PageRouteBuilder(
                        opaque: false,
                        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
                          return Registration();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                    print("Cliccato");
                  },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final void Function(String) onEmailChanged;
  final void Function(String) onPasswordChanged;

  const InputField({
    Key? key,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.onEmailChanged,
    required this.onPasswordChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Color(4294638330)))),
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: onEmailChanged,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Enter your email",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Color(4294638330)))),
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: onPasswordChanged,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Enter your password",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  final String password;

  const Button({
    Key? key,
    required this.password,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.cyan[500],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print(password);
          },
          child: Text(
            "Accedi",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, maybe I'm wrong. In InputWrapper I have Button and InputField where i have my email and password. In InputWrapper i add Email ,password and onEmailChanged, onPasswordChanged. In Button class I add email and password.

Comment: I'm sorry I am a bit noobie with Flutter and Dart

Comment: What did not work exactly ?

Comment: Email and password was null , i get a empty string

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Update your question with the new code if you want me to have a look

Comment: I try to manage my code without your tips. I hope it is clearer

Comment: Here you go, I updated my answer. Please do study how the argument are formed/passed, and what uses stateless vs stateful widgets.